# Is there a way to create a constraint that prevents updates in a SQL Server 2012 database table?

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I am creating an application that will track hours for employees. Ideally, HR has asked that certain tables not be modified once data is commited. This is done easily enough from the front-end and stored procedures. However, it would be great to be able to prevent it from the server itself through constraints so that folks that have access to the back-end data can't change any values in the selected tables (unless they are sneaky enough to know how to disable the constraints).

Comment: If each user has there own login into the server why wouldn't you just remove the permissions for update/insert/delete in a group and then add each user to that group?

Comment: You should be restricting control via permissions / access - not via table constraints....

First put down those restrictions, then see if you need to cover some corner cases with other things (like constraints...)

Comment: Agreed.  "Permissions" is how you handle this, not "Constraints".  Now, you could put some "audit triggers" that track a user_id....if someone manipulates the data.

Comment: Ok. So constraints aren't the way to go. Thanks guys for your input. I will look deeper into the permissions angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trust your SQL Server admins then it’s possible. Have your admin to create users that don’t have datawriter permissions for those tables or schema.

So, application would write the data into database and users who have access to those tables would only be able to read the data.

If you don’t want admins to have the ability to modify data that’s not possible. There is no way to prevent it but there is a way to detect it if it happens. Check out [this](http://blog.apexsql.com/2013/06/apexsql-comply-auditing-paradigm.html) article for details on details how to this is done in third party application and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Server Side security roles to give only the HR Group data-write privileges.